# Importing data from a table using the IMPORTXML function in Google Sheets

Tags: xml, import, google-sheets

First of all, I'm completely incompetent and my hours-long attempts at trying to make this work have been fruitless. So, please, talk to me like I don't know anything about coding, which is true, by the way.

Here it is:

```
<tr>
<td colspan="6" class="ar lt pb5">186,272</td>
</tr>
```

What I'm trying to import to a Google Sheets cell is the "186,272" bit.

The entire code can be found here: http://www.sportsclubstats.com/d/NHL/Western/Pacific/Edmontonlottery27D.xml (the "186,272" part is at the very end).

None of my attempts at pulling the right part of the table (or any part of it, really) through xpath_query have worked so far, and I'm 98% sure I'm doing something wrong.

Please, enlighten me.

Answer (score 0):

The correct xpath is :

```
//td[@class="ar lt pb5"][@colspan="6"]/text()
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still get a "formula parse error" when using this: =IMPORTXML('http://www.sportsclubstats.com/d/NHL/Western/Pacific/Edmontonlottery27D.xml', "//td[@class="ar lt pb5"][@colspan="6"]/text()")

Comment: I don't know the tools you are using. Test witl xmllint : `xmllint --xpath '//td[@class="ar lt pb5"][@colspan="6"]/text()' http://www.sportsclubstats.com/d/NHL/Western/Pacific/Edmontonlottery27D.xml
186,272`